# R, in topicmodels package, how to access to the objects of the class LDA?

Tags: r

I am working on [topicmodels R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/index.html), and trying to understand the following example that uses the `LDA` function and the lda object:

```
data("AssociatedPress", package = "topicmodels")
control = list(alpha = 0.1)
lda <- LDA(AssociatedPress[1:20,], k = 2, method=”VEM”, control)
lda_inf <- posterior(lda, AssociatedPress[21:30,])
```

I want to understand what's inside the lda instance.
From the package [instruction document](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/vignettes/topicmodels.pdf), I read that there are the following objects:

```
call: Object of class "call".
Dim: Object of class "integer"; number of documents and terms.
control: Object of class "TopicModelcontrol"; options used for estimating the topic model.
k: Object of class "integer"; number of topics.
terms: Vector containing the term names.
....
```

The problem is that I'm not able to access them. `lda$call` does not work.

How could I do it?
How could I read their content?

Comment: Don't know this package, but it seems that `LDA` returns an `S4` object, and as such you can access to its slots through the `@` operator. Try `lda@call` instead of `lda$call`.

Comment: @Nicola It works, thanks! :-) If you wrote it as answer, I'd accept it

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by the `LDA` function is an `S4` object and, as such, it is composed by *slots*. You can access them through the `@` operator. In this case, you need `lda@call` instead of `lda$call` to access the `call` slot of the object.

An `S4` object definition is obtained through `setClass`. The biggest difference between an `S4` object and a simple list is that you can modify as you wish the structure of a list (adding or removing elements), while the structure of an `S4` object is determined when you define its class and stays the same. For instance, if you try `lda@mynewslot<-1:10` you'll receive an error.